# The CLI seems to ignore my function and go to another! (Python)

Tags: python

```
from sys import exit

def dead(why):
    print why, "Better luck next time in the next life!"
    exit(0)

def strange_man():
    print """As you take way on to your adventure... You meet this strange man. 
    He tells you that he can not be trusted. He tells you that the door on the
    right is going to be good. He also tells you that the left door will lead you to good
    as well. But you cannot trust him... Which door do you pick?"""

    next = raw_input("Do you choose the left door or right? \n >")

    if next == "left" or "Left":
        good_door()
    elif next == "right" or "Right":
        evil_door()
    else:
        dead("You are drunk and can't seem to choose a door. Bye.")

def good_door():
    print """You seem to have chosen a door that has three distinct routes. You still do not know
    whether or not your choice of doors were correct... You hesitate to choose which route you take
    but you have to choose..."""

    next = raw_input("Which route do you choose? You have an option between Route 1, Route 2, or Route 3 \n >")

    if "Route 1" in next:
        print "Wow! You can't believe it! You are in heaven! You seem to have chosen the right door."
        exit(0)

    elif "Route 2" in next:
        desert()
    else:
        dead("You walk ahead into this route and then you suddenly fall and then a log hits your head, it seems like it was a trap. You're left a bloody mess.")

def desert():
    print """You walk into a desert and it's unbearably hot... You have two options... You stay here and hope
    that somebody will save you, or you keep walking... Which one do you choose?"""

    next = raw_input("Do you choose to stay or move? \n >")

    if "stay" in next:
        dead("You die of thirst")
    elif "move" in next:
        good_door()

def evil_door():
    print """You enter this door and you see two routes, which one do you choose?"""

    next = raw_input("You choose from the left route or the right route. \n >")
    if next == "left":
        good_door()
    else:
        dead("The route you chose seems to only go to Hell... You see satan and he eats you.")


strange_man()
```

My problem is in the strange_man function, when I choose "right" it goes back to the good_door function rather than the evil_door function as it is supposed to... I do not know why it is doing this! I seem to have it right :/

This is for ex36 in Learn Python The Hard Way where we make our own CLI text game...

Comment: There might be another minor flaw in the design: You keep on adding frames onto the call stack. So if your adventure grows longer you will reach max recursion depth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
next == "left" or "Left"
```

should be

```
next == "left" or next == "Left"
```

or

```
next in ["left", "Left"]
```

"Left" always resolves to True and `X or True` is always true.
The same holds for all your disjunctions.

In order to answer your comment, I personally would implement it like this: (This doesn't mean that your solution is less viable than mine, I just try to give some ideas)

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
from sys import exit

class Location:
    def __init__ (self, welcome, menu, choices):
        self.welcome = welcome
        self.choices = choices
        self.menu = menu

    def enter (self, *args):
        if not self.choices:
            print (args [0] )
            exit (0)
        print ('\n\n{}\n{}'.format ('*' * 20, self.welcome) )
        while True:
            print ()
            print (self.menu)
            print ('\n'.join ('{}: {}'.format (index + 1, text) for index, text in enumerate (choice [0] for choice in self.choices) ) )
            try:
                choice = int (input () )
                return self.choices [choice - 1] [1:]
            except: pass

class World:
    locations = {
        'Beginning': Location ('As you take way on to your adventure... You meet this strange man.\nHe tells you that he can not be trusted.\nHe tells you that the door on the right is going to be good. He also tells you that the left door will lead you to good as well. But you cannot trust him...', 'Which door do you pick?', [ ('Left', 'GoodDoor', [] ), ('Right', 'BadDoor', [] ) ] ),
        'GoodDoor': Location ('You seem to have chosen a door that has three distinct routes. You still do not know whether or not your choice of doors were correct... You hesitate to choose which route you take but you have to choose...', 'Which route do you choose?', [ ('Route 1', 'Finish', ['You are in heaven!'] ), ('Route 2', 'Desert', [] ), ('Route 3', 'Finish', ['You trip and die.'] ) ] ),
        'BadDoor': Location ('You enter this door and you see two routes, which one do you choose?', 'You choose from the left route or the right route.', [ ('Left', 'GoodDoor', [] ), ('Right', 'Finish', ['You ended in hell.'] ) ] ),
        'Finish': Location ('', '', [] ),
        'Desert': Location ('You walk into a desert and it\'s unbearably hot... You have two options... You stay here and hope that somebody will save you, or you keep walking... Which one do you choose?', 'Do you choose to stay or move?', [ ('Stay', 'Finish', ['You die of thirst'] ), ('Move', 'GoodDoor', [] ) ] )
        }

    @classmethod
    def enter (bananaphone):
        room = World.locations ['Beginning']
        params = []
        while True:
            room, params = room.enter (*params)
            room = World.locations [room]

World.enter ()
```

Hm, the syntax highlighter seems to mess up multi-line string literals.

The reason why I reference the locations by names and not simply by reference is in order to allow loops in the graph.

Comment: That seemed to have made it work! Thank you so much. I never knew you have to add another boolean statement for a "or" keyword. And you showed me a simpler way to add more possibilities without having to use "or". Thanks!

Comment: Thanks alot for the improved code! I actually never thought of it like that! I'm pretty beginner so this helped alot! I appreciate the time you took!

Comment: I'm also a bit confused as to how farther could I go without reaching Max recursion? I font quite understand the idea behind it.

Comment: Each time you call a function inside a function you put a new frame onto the call stack. Most python implementations allow by default a maximum number of 500 stack frames (although you can raise it, but not indefinitely. And python doesn't allow for LCO). So if you have two functions that call each other mutually like room1 () calls room2() and vice verse, if you walk often enough in circles you will reach max recursion depth. Therefore in my example I derecursified (linearized) this.

Comment: So when using the basic idea of my last post, you will not have to worry about recursion. The idea is: Don't let the rooms call each other, but call one room and this room returns the next room. Then, on the same frame where you call the first room, you call the next room and so on. This happens in the `while True` loop.